# How to get flipkart product data using web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-3.5

If I run below code I don't get anything. Can you please find out what is problem in my code.

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=laptop')
content = r.content.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode(encoding='UTF-8'), "lxml")
reviews = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "_3wU53n"})
print(reviews)
```

Expecting result:

```
HP Core i3 6th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) 1AC75PA#ACJ 15-BE012TU Notebook
```

Comment: The content is loaded dynamically, check the source if the class exists.

Comment: Sorry, i checked page source class is not there.. if data is dynamic how can i get the data?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems perfect to me. I ran your exact code and with a bit of manipulations, I was able to get the desired result:

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=laptop')
content = r.content.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode(encoding='UTF-8'), "lxml")
reviews = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "_3wU53n"})
for item in reviews:
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

HP 15q Core i3 7th Gen - (8 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) 15q-bu038TU Laptop

Dell Vostro 15 3000 Core i5 8th Gen - (8 GB/1 TB HDD/Windows 10 Home/2 GB Graphics) 3578 Laptop ...

...
and so on

Try to run the code from anywhere else, may be flipkart blocked your IP, if you are pinging them with too many requests

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4  
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  
myurl = "https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&marketplace=FLIPKART&otracker=start&as-show=on&as=off"  
uclient = uReq(myurl)       
page_html = uclient.read()  
uclient.close()  
psoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")  
container= psoup.findAll("div",{"class":"bhgxx2 col-12-12"})  
#container variable contains the html of product title which is store in div tag and class is bhgxx2   
y=[]  
Y is array for Store all Product Titles   
for Product in container:  
 ProductTitle = Product.findAll("div",{"class":"_3wU53n"})  
 for i in ProductTitle:  
    print(i.text)  
#All product Title will appear on Flipkart page according to url
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer, and correct your code formatting?